# How to set Fileinput directory value from properties?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

If my flow is `File Input` -> `Compute Node` -> `File Output`, how can I set the `File Input` directory value based on a User Defined Property? I will have a different file drop directory for dev, qa and prod and don’t want this hard coded anywhere. If it cannot be done using my User Defined Properties, how else can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do not use the [tag:esql] tag on SO because it is ambiguous.
Use one of the tags [tag:embedded-sql], [tag:entity-sql] or
[tag:extended-sql], depending on which variant of ESQL you wish to ask
about.
See the [ESQL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/esql/info) for more
information about which to use if it is not immediately obvious to you.
(It isn't obvious to me from the information in the question whether you need to use [tag:extended-sql] or [tag:entity-sql].)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create [configurable properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bn22250_.htm) per environment and define the input directory there.

Properties for `dev`:

```
# File: yourapp-dev.properties
yourflow#File Input.inputDirectory = ./yourapp/dev/in
```

Properties for `qa`:

```
# File: yourapp-qa.properties
yourflow#File Input.inputDirectory = ./yourapp/qa/in
```

Apply the properties per environment. For `dev` it would be:

```
mqsiapplybaroverride -b yourapp.bar -p yourapp-dev.properties -r
```

Now you can deploy `yourapp.bar` to the `dev` environment.

Comment: This was what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. If it answered your question, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).